# Is the Stalwart Numen always on?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

The Stalwart Numen reads slightly differently to the other numina.
Most clearly read like the activated abilities they are.

Page 228:

> Each Numen is a single ability linked to the entity’s  nature —
> activated by a successful Power + Finesse roll unless  stated
> otherwise.

Page 230:

> #### Stalwart
>
> The entity appears armored in Twilight form and uses
> Resistance as its Defense score instead of the lower of Power  or
> Finesse.

It doesn't talk about it activates. For instance, it doesn't say "Entity morphs to grow armour in its twilight form".
Also unlike the other Numina it doesn't state a cost in essence to activate.

Compare (Page 229):

> #### Innocuous
>
> The entity is very good at being overlooked. Perception
> rolls to notice the entity are penalized by 2 dice. This Numen does
> not require a roll to activate and has no cost.

Which makes it clear Innocuous is always on.

**Is Stalwart always on (like Innocuous), or does it have to be activated?**

**If so, how long does it last?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
it is always active.
You should treat it the same as Innocuous

An example of this can be see in the stat block for  the angel:
 Drawbridge (**Page 257 Demon the Decent**):

He has :

- Power 8,
- Finesse 8,
- Resistance 9,
- and the Stalwart Numen.
- His defence is listed as 9.

If Stalwart was not always on it would be recorded as 8.